# Lost my windows product key and the hard drive is dead , and this has no cd : How do I recover?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, product-key

I had windows 7 Professional running on this machine. I got this machine from my attic, but the key and Cd are lost. The HDD died a while ago and doesn't get detected in the BIOS. Is there anyway of getting the product key so i can install Windows ? Currently I am running ubuntu 16.04 live from a USB key.

Comment: Without the key the license cannot be used or recovered, my suggestion, just accept you shouldn't have lost the license key and purchase a new Windows license

Answer (score 0):

If the hard drive is dead, you can't get the installed key, and you have no product key then you're out of luck.  If there was some way to genuinely activate without anything of that sort you can bet that pirates would have already been all over it.

Edit: if you can get the hard drive working, then [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) will tell you the product key of the installation.